# Need a way to prevent phone wakeup when slider opens

Tags: power-on, standby

Is there a way to stop my phone from waking itself when the slider opens? Because my phone does things in my pockets :(

Comment: What phone do you have?

Comment: @Al Motorola Milestone :/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use the unlock pattern instead of the swipe to unlock screen.

It is far less likely that your pocket will manage to input your entire unlock pattern, thus the device will do nothing even if some touchevents do get sent to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sliding action may be a "key" trigger that has a key code assigned to it. You can modify such keys if you are rooted. (you can confirm this by running the hardware key test inside ClockWork Mod Recovery, then simply slide the phone and see a key code is shown)

Then you can use the Button ReMapper app to change the WAKE of that key to something else that isn't wake. (Be warned though, you should have some other button to WAKE your phone up or else you will be stuck without finding a way to wake your phone)

Follow the instructions of Button ReMapper over at the XDA : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464

Please don't hold me responsible for any damages, do it only if you feel like.